# How to RewriteRule if file exists elsewhere

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to accomplish the same as many frameworks do: having the request processed by a .php (namely, index.php), while keeping a `/application/public` folder which contains all the elements that should be shown in case they exist. For example:

```
folder /application/public
total 28K
92897619 drwxr-xr-x 5 1001 1001 4.0K Jul 29 00:07 .
92897616 drwxr-xr-x 7 1001 1001 4.0K Jul 28 23:31 ..
92897754 -rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   15 Jul 29 00:07 .htaccess
92897733 drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001 4.0K Jul 28 23:31 images
92897620 -rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  696 Jul 28 23:58 index.php
92897625 drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001 4.0K Jul 28 23:31 javascript
92897734 drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001 4.0K Jul 28 23:31 stylesheets

folder /:
total 24K
92831996 drwxr-xr-x 4 1001 1001 4.0K Jul 29 02:44 .
91980897 drwxr-xr-x 5    0    0 4.0K Jul  6 00:30 ..
92831975 -rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  360 Jul 29 02:44 .htaccess
92897616 drwxr-xr-x 7 1001 1001 4.0K Jul 28 23:31 application
92832733 -rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  696 Jul 29 00:02 index.php
92897739 drwxr-xr-x 6 1001 1001 4.0K Jul 28 23:31 system
```

If there is a request for `example.com/images/a.jpg`, `/application/public/images/a.jpg` should be shown, as it exists. Otherwise, index.php would get `?uri=images/a.jpg` as query string.

With this in mind, I wrote the following .htaccess (placed at /):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/public%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ application/public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ index.php?uri=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
```

Still, requesting for anything existent at `/application/public` redirects the request to `index.php` (for example, `example.com/images/a.jpg` ends up being `example.com/index.php?uri=images/a.jpg`).

Apache logs only show the following (when requesting `example.com/javascript/index.php`):

> File does not exist: /home/jbayardo/www/test/javascript

This, as you can imagine, leaves me in the blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add `[OR]` at the end of first RewriteCond line.

   Currently the logic is `AND`: currently it reads as *"if it is a file that exists AND if it is a folder that exists"* .. which cannot be true -- conditions are not satisfied and rewrite does not occur.

   You need *"if it is a file that exists OR if it is a folder that exists"*.

   See docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond (you have to scroll down a bit).
2. Even if rule #1 will work properly, it will still end up rewritten to `index.php?uri=$1` -- because that what you are telling Apache to do. You need to add a condition to prevent rewriting already rewritten URLs (keep in mind, that when Apache rewrites URL, it goes to next iteration ans start matching all rules again from top -- that is how it works).
3. The `?` in RewriteRule patterns are not needed.

This is how I see it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/public%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ application/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(application/public/|index.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
```